# pysal AssertionError terminator == '\r'

Tags: python, pysal

I am trying to convert a `.dbf` file to a `pandas.DataFrame`. However, I am getting an error from the following line of code:

```py
dbf = ps.open(dbf_link)
```

> File "/Users/UserName/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysal/core/IOHandlers/pyDbfIO.py", line 77, in **init**
>       assert terminator == '\r'
>   AssertionError

Heres my code:

```
import pysal as ps
import pandas as pd

dbf_link = '//Users/UserName/pyProjects/I_cst.Dbf'
dbf = ps.open(dbf_link)
d = {col: dbf.by_col(col) for col in dbf.header}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: Sounds like your DBF is corrupt, or there's a bug in the PySAL dbf reader.  You can try running python with the -O flag which will disable assert statements. Can you verify the bug with another DBF?